# saving parent data without saving child data using jpa

Tags: java, web-services, jpa

I am saving data using jpa in parent and child table, but I need below:

1. Saving both parent and child table.  If I am passing the request from soap or rest client both parent and child data.
2. Saving only parent.  If I am passing parent json and empty child json meaning not inserted into child, only inserted into parent.

Like my entities are:

> Parent :Apartment child :Room

Please give me suggestions. I blocked my whole day for this one and I am new to jpa.

Comment: add the entity classes, lets see them

Comment: In your (2) scenario, would the `Parent` be new and you simply don't need to associate any new `Child` rows with it?